# How to implement subdomain-based module in revel

Tags: go, revel

I was wondering is there any example or good practice in Revel of making application module, related to subdomain.

For example, we have `site.com`, which is default application module and want to add an additional `admin` module for `admin.site.com` subdomain. The main problem I can see at this point is that we need to

1. dynamically determine what module should be used (using an interceptor before request)
2. switch routing in order to avoid collisions (since there may be overlapping routes, such as `/` for default module and `/` for admin module)

Does anyone implemented such application architecture in revel? Any related advice would be very helpful.

Comment: are you using something in front of revel app (like nginx) or is it running on 80 or 443 port?

Comment: @pregmatch, nothing at the moment, for now it's in development state, didn't consider deployment so far